# EOF- and SocketException in simple server client program

Tags: java, networking

I wrote a simple server client program today, but I have a problem and don't know why.
Here are my 3 important classes(all methods are called properly):

```
    public class Server {
    private ServerSocket server;
    private ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            server.setSoTimeout(900000);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        acceptClients();
        Main.frame.log("Server started on port "+port);
    }
    public void acceptClients() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("Accepting");
                while(true) {
                    try {
                        Socket client = server.accept();
                        System.out.println("Accepted: "+client.getLocalSocketAddress());
                        clients.add(new Client(client));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }

}

    public class Client {
    private static Socket client;
    private static DataOutputStream out;
    private static DataInputStream in;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        client = new Socket("localhost", 1567);
        client.setSoTimeout(900000);
        in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
        receive();
        send("Hi I am a client!");
    }

    public static void receive() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        String data = in.readUTF();
                        System.out.println("Received: "+data);
                        send("Test");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
        };
        t.start();
    }

    public static void send(String data) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Sending");
            out.writeUTF(data);
            System.out.println("Sent: "+data);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The client handler of my server:

```
    public class Client {
    Socket socket;
    DataOutputStream out;
    DataInputStream in;
    public Client(Socket client) {
        socket = client;
        try {
            socket.setSoTimeout(900000);
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            receive();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void receive() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        process(in.readUTF());
                        in.close();
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
    public void send(String data) {
        try {
            out.writeUTF(data);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void process(String data) {
        Main.frame.log("Received--> "+data);
        send("I received your message!");
    }

}
```

When I execute the server and the client everything is fine until the client sends the second message. Then I get this error from the server:

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at de.julian.factoryserver.net.Client$1.run(Client.java:33)
```

And this error from my client:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(Unknown Source)
    at ftc.Client$1.run(Client.java:28)
```

I hope someone can help me!

Comment: Your client program ends after `send("Hi I am a client!");` therefore the JVM terminates and the socket connection is closed. In your end method you should `flush()` the connection to make sure the data has really been sent and not cached locally.

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. Also the program doesn't end because of the while true. Actually it sends the "Hi I am a client" and also receives the answer of the server, but fails when sending "Test".

Comment: You are sending for multiple threads (main and the new created one) this can end up in both threads sending at the same time. You should make the `send` method `synchronized`.

Comment: I did that, but it didn't help either. Also they can't send at the same time because the receive thread waits until it receives something and it only receives something after it sent something

Comment: Nothing should be `static` here. At present you can't handle multiple clients correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `Server`, in method `send` you seem to have closed the outputstream, dont close it, just flush it

```
 public void send(String data) {
        try {
            out.writeUTF(data);
            out.close(); // remove this and replace it with out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

also in `recieve` you seem to prematurely close the inputstream

```
private void receive() {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        process(in.readUTF());
                        in.close(); // remove this
                        sleep(100);
                    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Apply the above fixes and that should fix your exceptions.